# Matching data frames

Tags: r, regex, match

I have this code:

```
df1 <- data.frame(letter=c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
              value=c(NA))
df2 <- data.frame(letter=c("a", "b", "g", "f", "d", "e", "a", "b", "a", "c"),
              number=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10))
```

I want to match these two data frames by letter and return the corresponding number in df2 into the Value column in df1.

So the result for df1 would look this this:

[image]

Comment: `df2[match(df1$letter, df2$letter),]`

Comment: Looks like you want to join by location too. You could `library(data.table); setDT(df1)[, indx := rowid(letter)]; setDT(df2)[, indx := rowid(letter)] ;df1[df2, value := number, on = .(letter, indx)]` (don't predefine `value=c(NA)` in `df1` please at it creates a logical vector instead of numeric)

Comment: @PierreLafortune It's not what they want.

Comment: This just returns the position of which the letter in df1 appears in df2. I'm more so interested in returning the number associated with each instance of that letter in df2. For example, for letter "a" I'd want to return the numbers 1, 7, 9

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks. Exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: The result row `4 b 3` should presumably be `4 b 2`.

Comment: (a) Is the number of occurrences of each letter in `df1` always equal to the number of occurrences of that letter in `df2`? (b) Are the letters in `df1` always sorted?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to match these two data frames by letter

This can be accomplished with [merge](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/merge.html) and [unique](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/unique.html):

```
> df = unique(merge(df1['letter'], df2))
> df
   letter number
1       a      1
2       a      9
3       a      7
10      b      2
11      b      8
14      c     10
15      d      5
16      e      6
```

- almost, since the number values for each letter might not be sorted as you want, so let's sort them

> and return the corresponding number in df2 into the Value column in df1.

```
> df1$value = df$number[order(df$letter, df$number)]
> df1
  letter value
1      a     1
2      a     7
3      a     9
4      b     2
5      b     8
6      c    10
7      d     5
8      e     6
```

Answer (score -1):

Look at the package dplyr with the join functions :

```
library(dplyr)
inner_join(df1, df2) %>%
  distinct(letter, number)
```

Comment: Seriously? How about you look at the desired output first

Comment: This just returns the position of which the letter in df1 appears in df2. I'm more so interested in returning the number associated with each instance of that letter in df2. For example, for letter "a" I'd want to return the numbers 1, 7, 9

Comment: I'm sorry, but my solution returns exactly the output needed (ok, I added the distinct function afterward). Sorry if I don't understand the problem...